# How to get id of selected option with jsp?

Tags: html, jsp, html-select

I have something like this in HTML:

```
<select name="selection">
    <option id="1">First Option</option>
    ...
</select>
```

I would like to get the ID of the selected option in JSP. request.getParameter("selection") gives me the text of the option but I want the id.

Comment: Just add value attribute. <option id="1" value="1">

Comment: While most if not all browsers are forgiving in this, IDs starting with a digit are illegal in HTML. I also think that you need to realize that the `id` really serves an entirely different purpose than representing the input value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keeping `id` and `value` same will work for you.

e.g.

```
<option id="1" value="1">First Option</option>
```